# Order by using month name in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, sql-order-by

I have a table which has a field Month_Name and it contains the names of the month. I want to ORDER BY the month names, not alphabetically, but by its actual order, like, January, February, etc. How can I implement this using PostgreSQL?

Is there any way that I can convert the Month Name to its numeric value?

```
id        billed_unit    billed_amount    town_id    ea_month    ea_year    
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     April         2014
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     August        2014
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     February      2014
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     July          2014
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     June          2014
3959920   3695.17        25856.84         CHRY     March         2014
```

Comment: whats the field type of `Month_Name` ??

Comment: its character varying

Comment: show the select query that you want to _ORDER BY_

Comment: SELECT * FROM EA.TOWN_CONS_BILLING_ROLLUP WHERE TOWN_ID='CHRY' AND EA_YEAR=2014 ORDER BY ea_month;

I'll put my output for this query in the Question

Comment: a sample month-name ?? just to know whether it 'Jan' or 'January'

Comment: Please check the update question. This is the output that I am getting. But I need February's record first followed by March and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM EA.TOWN_CONS_BILLING_ROLLUP 
WHERE TOWN_ID='CHRY' 
      AND EA_YEAR=2014 
ORDER BY   
to_date(ea_month,'Month');
```

[Data Type Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: @YousufIbnAkhtarSultan go through `PostgreSQL documentations`

Comment: @IbrahimMohammed I never said that this solution works with `distinct on()`

Comment: sorry i understand you didn't but i was trying it, so i thought you would have a solution for it since i can't get around it

Comment: @IbrahimMohammed Open a new question. You would get answers if the question meets SO requirements.