# Order By Month Name - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I followed this post [Order by using month name in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932178/order-by-using-month-name-in-postgresql) but not success!

I have a query (its working) and I just need to order the results by mont name.  This is thr query I am using:

```
   select to_char(purchase_date, 'Month') as mes_2021,
           sum(gmv::float4) as soma_gmv
           from tablename
    where purchase_date > '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY mes_2021
```

I am trying:

```
order by to_date(purchase_date, 'Month') - No success
order by date_part(purchase_date::date, 'Month') - No success
```

If i use `order by mes_2021`

[image]

Comment: Any reason your code excludes January 1?

Comment: not sure if i understand but January is there, right? oh, now i see '>' instead of '>=' Thanks

Comment: . . `purchase_date > '2021-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is to use a window function on the date:

```
select to_char(purchase_date, 'Month') as mes_2021,
       sum(gmv::float4) as soma_gmv
from tablename
where purchase_date > '2021-01-01'
group by mes_2021
order by min(purchase_date);
```

This, of course, assumes that the dates are all in the same year.  But your `where` clause is taking care of that.